# HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request using python-firebase

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload data to firebase realtime database using python-firebase but I'm getting the following error:
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://app.firebaseio.com/essential/activepassive/.json
My code:

```
from firebase import firebase 
firebase=firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://app.firebaseio.com/',None)
firebase.post('/essential/activepassive',dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 means an Invalid JSON in your request:you may have '#' or other invalid character in your json file.

you can use this data for test

```
data_good = {'url': 'url1', 'address': 'address1','name': 'name1'}
```